# NodeJs & MongoDb , find data in a collection and insert it to another collection

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, schema, mongoose-schema

I want to perform a **database** **migration** from an old model to another .

I have a database in MongoDB inside *2* *collection* the first one represents the old model and the other one present the model that the data would be transfer to it .
Thank you for sharing with me if there is a way to get the job done , perhaps a link or anything that could help please.

***Note***: example i get the data from **large** (instance of the old model) i must get it and transfer it to another instance **width** (step by step till having the second model).

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

async function main() {
    const MONGO_URL = process.env.MONGO_URL || '';

    const client = new MongoClient(MONGO_URL);

    await listDatabases(client);

    try {
        await client.connect();
        console.log('server is connected');
    } finally {
        await client.close();
    }
}
main().catch(console.error);

async function listDatabases(client: { db: (arg0: string) => { (): any; new (): any; admin: { (): { (): any; new (): any; listDatabases: { (): any; new (): any } }; new (): any } } }) {
    const databases = await client.db('park').admin().listDatabases();
    console.log('Databases:');
    databases.databases.forEach((db: { name: any }) => console.log(` - ${db.name}`));
}
async function ...{

}
```

Comment: And your problem/question is?

Comment: how i can make the job done , migrate the first collection into the other one